# Unable to update value of QuillNoSSRWrapper in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on reactjS and I am using the nextjs framework. Right now I'm working on "update module" (blog update) functionality using the `QuillNoSSRWrapper` editor. At the moment, the editor is showing a value but I'm unable to type anything into the editor. How can I fix this? Here is my current code:

```
const Post =  function(props) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
}

<QuillNoSSRWrapper modules={modules}  theme="snow" onChange={(content) => {
  setContent(content);
}} value='abc'/>
```

Comment: You need to pass your state to the wrapper - `value={content}`

Comment: @Lain Shelvington i did ( then i tried with static) but not worked for me

Comment: @lain Shelvington How can i fix this kindly tell me

Answer (score 1):

change the value to 'contnet'
example:

```
const Post =  function(props) {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('abc');  
  return <QuillNoSSRWrapper modules={modules}  theme="snow" onChange={(content) => {
    setContent(content);
  }} value={content}/>
}
export default Post
```